# variable inside variable in a PHP function?

Tags: php, function, variables

I have the following function.

The problem is that the $lang variable will vary depending on the `$this->setts['site_lang'];` . The actual problem is the following:

```
$condition_details['description_$lang']
```

(which isn't working). How do I get this to display

```
$condition_details['description_us']
```

or

```
$condition_details['description_fr']
```

depending on the $lang setting?

And here is the full function:

```
function shipped_drop_down($box_name = 'item_shipped_via', $selected = null, $form_refresh = null)
{
    (string) $display_output = null;
    $lang = $this->setts['site_lang'];
    $sql_select_conditions = $this->query("SELECT id, description_".$lang." FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "advanced_shipping_carriers ORDER BY theorder,description_".$lang." ASC");
    $display_output = '<select name="' . $box_name . '" ' . (($form_refresh) ? 'onChange = "submit_form(' . $form_refresh . ', \'\')"' : '') . ' style="font-size:10px; width: 120px;"> ';
    while ($condition_details = $this->fetch_array($sql_select_conditions))
    {
        $display_output .= '<option value="' . $condition_details['id'] . '" ' . (($condition_details['id'] == $selected) ? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $condition_details['description_$lang'] . '</option> ';
    }
    $display_output .= '</select> ';
    return $display_output;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
$condition_details['description_'.$lang]
```

or use `"`

```
$condition_details["description_$lang"]
```

Comment: `$condition_details["description_{$lang}"]` is the more correct way, although both will work.

Comment: @iMoses: How exactly "more correct"? Here's an argument for the other approach: basic syntax highlighting will make it obvious that you have a variable key name at a glance.

Comment: @iMoses do you get anynotice from the compiler if i use that as i do?Why do you say it's more correct?

Comment: Perhaps "correct" wasn't the correct word :)
Using curly braces when inserting a variable into a double quoted string serves several purposes. The first is making sure that in no situation the compiler will mix variable names with simple string, i.e. `$files["My$CatNameFolder"]` - `$CatName` being the variable, the compiler will look for `$CatNameFolder`. By using curly braces we help the compiler not make assumptions and pass the exact variable name we wanted.

Comment: Other then that using curly braces allow you to use complex expressions which are normally not allowed, e.g. arrays `"My {$array[$key]}"`, objects `"My {$object->value()}"` and some other cool stuff `"My {$object->{$method}()}"`, `"My {${$result ? 'var1' : 'var2'}}"` and more.

Comment: @iMoses thanks for pointing that out, it's useful, i knew those things i just though i was missing something! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could store your lang settings in arrays like this :

```
$lang['fr']['condition_details']
```

so you could use `$lang[$selected_lang]['condition_details']`

Answer (score 1):

Use "double quotes" instead of 'single quotes'. That way the `$lang` will be parsed and replaced with the relevant value.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes like so:

```
$condition_details["description_$lang"]
```

Comment: @SenorAmor: Not my downvote, but a small issue here is that by not including curly braces around the variable it's easier for the code to break in the future.

Comment: @Jon By that logic, all the answers here should be marked down for not strictly typecasting `$lang` as a string.  There's no "issue" here providing one is a competent coder.  Being marked down for not "bubble-wrapping" code is a load of crap.  Don't even get me started on anonymous down-voting...

Comment: @SenorAmor: Dude, I just offered a suggestion on how to improve the answer (albeit very slightly). Drawing the conclusion that you actually got downvoted for this reason is totally illogical, and getting "competent coder" defensive is not productive for anyone. Loosen up.

Comment: @Jon I'm fine.  I didn't mean to imply that your reason was the correct one.  It was more a rant about SO. :)